# If in a String adjacent letters occurring in the word are same then print "same" otherwise "diff"

Tags: java

I am trying but for sometime input 4 integer it will give wrong output . please update my code or give me some idea. Below is my sample output. and the code which i am trying.

Example output:-

```
input:-
3
remember
occurring
apple



diff
Same
same
```

Code:-

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a number");
int flag=1;

int a=sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i <a; i++) {

    System.out.println("enter a string");
    String s=sc.next();
    char [] sq=s.toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < sq.length-1; j++) {
        if(sq[j]==sq[j+1]) {
            flag=0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag==1) {
        System.out.println("diff");
    } else {
        System.out.println("same");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also post the inputs for which you don't get proper results?

Comment: input:-
4
remember
occurring
apple
qwert

diff
Same
same
same

Here i am getting same for input "qwert" but  i want "diff"

Comment: when you ask for **3** you are supposed to type after that **3** strings ! not more ... your code works fine !!

Comment: got it, looks like the flag is not reset as others indicated.

Comment: yes, that's what i just found hhh

Comment: @thanks everyone....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just use Regex:** short and simpler

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "dess";
    boolean match = s.matches(".*([A-Za-z])\\1+.*");

    if (match)
        System.out.println("same");
    else
        System.out.println("diff");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you were not resetting your flag to the initial value between each run.  Notice that I have changed your flag to a Boolean value rather then an integer and it now resets just before the System.out.println();

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    boolean flag=true;

    int a=sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <a; i++) {

        flag=true;
        System.out.println("enter a string");
        String s=sc.next();
        char [] sq=s.toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < sq.length-1; j++) 
        {

            if(sq[j]==sq[j+1])
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("diff");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("same");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: no problem, you might also try using names rather then letters for your variables like numOfStrings for a, stringToCheck for sq and tempString for s.  makes your code much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you code is that your never reset your flag. If you have a 'same' case then you flag will stay at 0 for the rest of the excution time of the program. And therefore all cases after the first 'same' will also yield 'same'. To solve this simple move your `flag = 0` code to inside the first while loop. Like somewhere here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <a; i++) {
   flag = 1;//<-- reset your flag variable
   System.out.println("enter a string");
   String s=sc.next();
   char [] sq=s.toCharArray();
   for (int j = 0; j < sq.length-1; j++) 
   {
       etc....
```

That should solve your problem.
I hope this helps :)